# How to install Spyder-terminal in Python 3.8 or 3.9 with Spyder v4.3.x or Spyder 5.0.x

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

Spyder-terminal does not install with Anaconda Navigator running Python v3.8 or v3.9 or v3.10.

My question is "Is there a way to install the Spyder-Terminal Plugin using Anaconda Navigator running Python 3.8 or 3.9 or 3.10, and use Spyder v5.x " ?

Is there a hack for this to run inside Spyder 5.0.x on Python 3.8, 3.9 or 3.10, WITHOUT creating a new virtual environment?

### My Software Versions

- Spyder-Terminal Version:  spyder-terminal-0.5.0 (spyder-ide/win-64)
- Python Version:  3.8 or 3.9
- Anaconda v2.0.1
- Operating system:  Windows 10

What I tried:

I tried installing 'conda install -c spyder-ide spyder-terminal' from Anaconda Command Prompt.  I did several trials with MANY errors to learn that Spyder-terminal only works with Spyder v4.2 and NOT Spyder v5.0.3.

Spyder-terminal is (nominally) supposed to work in Python 3.9.  So I tried upgrading Anaconda base environment to Python 3.9.  However, that BROKE the Anaconda base environment, which required uninstalling and reinstalling the entire Anaconda distribution.  (What a hassle.  Good thing this was on someone else's computer! 8^))

I finally got it to work in a separate conda virtual environment running Python 3.6.  Just to be conservative, I used Python 3.6 instead of Python 3.7.  (I later installed Spyder-Terminal in a Python 3.7-based virtual environment and it worked fine.)

The steps that finally worked were to Create a new conda environment with Python 3.6 and install spyder-terminal and spyder-notebook there.

I used the following commands...

```
conda create -n python36 -c conda-forge python=3.6
conda install spyder-terminal -c conda-forge spyder-ide
conda install spyder-notebook -c conda-forge spyder-ide
```

The correct version of Spyder (for Python 3.6) was installed along with all of its correct dependencies.

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. try installing into an Anaconda distribution with Python 3.8 or Python 3.9 kernels
2. Wait a long time and get many errors.
3. Rip out a few locks of hair (preferably someone else's)

**What is the expected output?

Spyder-Terminal plugin installs and is available for use.

**What do you see instead?**

A bunch of errors.  The exact errors were lost when I closed the installation console.

###### Suggestions

The Spyder-terminal plugin failed repeatedly in Anaconda "base" running v3.8.x or a new environment running v3.9.x.  I used a new conda virtual environment, running Python 3.6 runtime kernel and install spyder-terminal there.

The Spyder-terminal installer should do version checks for Python and Spyder FIRST, warn the user, and stop if they are not using Python 3.6 or Python 3.7.

Clearer documentation for Spyder-Terminal plugin installation on the Github.com home page (or built into Spyder Menu "Help" will help the "HELP" system.  These docs should state WHICH version(s) of Spyder and Python that Spyder-Terminal v0.5.x requires.  A dependency table would also be useful.

Comment: This problem still persists and cost me a few hours so far. Cumbersome, to say the least.